# On-Demand Backup/Restore for Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Servers

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

Hi StackOverflow Community,

Can you please tell me if Azure PostgreSQL flexible servers support on-demand backup ?

As I understand on-demand backup is supported just for Azure PostgreSQL single server.

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no not supported yet however there is a plan to add the capability by next year.